# query result took from wordpress database showing as question marks

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, utf-8

I have saved Telugu language content in the database with utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation, and I am trying to extract that information from a different place (Not WordPress environment) everything ok but Telugu characters are showing as question marks.

this is the content stored in the database.
    ఆ ఒక్క మాట తో కంపెనీ సర్వ నాశనం | #OURMINE | #VEVO
This is the text i am getting.
   ? ???? ??? ?? ?????? ???? ????? | #OurMine | #Vevo

Code i used to get the information.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db","pw","db");
    mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $con);
 // Check connection 
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM TT_posts WHERE post_status='publish' AND ping_status='open'";
 mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $query);
 $result = $con->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())   {
    ?>
<?php  
  $image = "SELECT * FROM TT_posts WHERE post_parent='$row[ID]' AND 
post_title='FEATURED' AND post_type='attachment'";
  $result1 = $con->query($image); 
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc())
    $img = $row1[guid]; 
 ?>

<div class="featured-thumbnail"><?php echo '<img src="'.$img.'">';?></div>
<header>
<h3 class="featured-category-title"><?php echo $row[post_title];?></h3>
</header>
<?php } ?>
```

I don't know where i am wrong.

Comment: Always query the WP database using `$wpdb` instance.

Comment: $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM TT_posts WHERE post_status='publish' AND ping_status='open'")

Comment: @Junaid did that but no use

Comment: And when you view the WP posts using the theme, then it look fine?

Comment: You likely neglected to specify the correct character encoding in some place - so go check the duplicate, it shows you what to look for.

Comment: @CBroe it worked, Thank You.

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored